# SpringBootApplication not scanning components

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I read many people asked the same question but I have followed all the rules, and I don't know what am I missing

I have following:

Main

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Model

```
package com.example.demo.model;

import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "ivsd_account")
public class Account implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "acc_id")
    private Long accId;

    @Column(name = "acc_uid", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String accUid;

    @Column(name = "acc_created_by_acc_uid")
    private String accCreatedByAccUid;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "acc_created_date")
    private Date accCreatedDate;

    @Column(name = "acc_updated_by_acc_uid")
    private String accUpdatedByAccUid;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "acc_updated_date")
    private Date accUpdatedDate;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "acc_sync_tst")
    private Date accSyncTst;

    @Column(name = "acc_enabled")
    private Boolean accEnabled;

    @Column(name = "acc_name")
    private String accName;

    @Column(name = "acc_email")
    private String accEmail;

    @Column(name = "acc_username")
    private String accUsername;

    @Column(name = "acc_password")
    private String accPassword;

getters and setters
```

DTO

```
package com.example.demo.dto;


import com.example.demo.model.Account;

import java.util.Date;

public class AccountDTO {

    private Long accId;

    private String accUid;

    private String accCreatedByAccUid;

    private Date accCreatedDate;

    private String accUpdatedByAccUid;

    private Date accUpdatedDate;

    private Date accSyncTst;

    private Boolean accEnabled;

    private String accName;

    private String accEmail;

    private String accUsername;

    private String accPassword;

getters and setters
```

Repository

```
package com.example.demo.repository;

import com.example.demo.model.Account;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends CustomRepository<Account, Long> {

    Account findOneByAccName(String name);

    Account findByAccUid(String uid);

    Account findByAccEmail(String email);

    void deleteAccountByAccUid(String uid);

}
```

Service

```
package com.example.demo.service;

import com.example.demo.dto.AccountDTO;
import com.example.demo.mapper.AccountMapper;
import com.example.demo.model.Account;
import com.example.demo.repository.AccountRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class AccountService {

    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @Autowired
    private AccountMapper accountMapper; // Could not autowire. No beans of AccountMapper type found

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<AccountDTO> loadAll() {
        List<Account> res = accountRepository.findAll();
        List<AccountDTO> resF = accountMapper.entitiesToDto(res);
        return resF;
    }
```

Controller

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import com.example.demo.service.AccountService;
import com.example.demo.dto.AccountDTO;
import com.example.demo.system.ResponseWrapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class AccountController {

    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/accounts", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> loadAll() {
        List<AccountDTO> res = accountService.loadAll();
        return new ResponseEntity(new ResponseWrapper(res), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Mapper

```
package com.example.demo.mapper;

import com.example.demo.dto.AccountDTO;
import com.example.demo.model.Account;
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.MappingTarget;
import org.mapstruct.ReportingPolicy;

import java.util.List;

@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE, componentModel = "spring")
public interface AccountMapper {

    AccountDTO entityToDto(Account entity);

    Account dtoToEntity(AccountDTO entity);

    Account updateEntityFromDto(AccountDTO dto, @MappingTarget Account entity);

    List<AccountDTO> entitiesToDto(List<Account> entities);
}
```

I get an error in Service:

Field accountMapper in com.example.demo.service.AccountService required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.mapper.AccountMapper' that could not be found.

I have placed all the classes in sub packages of the package from Main class.

If I add annotation @ComponentScan("com.example.demo.mapper") then it works only for mapper package, other packages are not scanned. Sorry for stupid question. Any help I appreciate

Thank you

Comment: Try @ComponentScan("com.example.demo") to scan all mentioned packages.

Comment: I don't see the mapper being annotated with any spring-related annotations, so how is that supposed to work?

Comment: @kemot90 `@SpringBootApplication` will implicitly component-scan the package of the class where the annotation is added, as well as sub-packages to this.

Comment: @Tobb MapStruct should add the necessary annotations on the generated classes, when the componentModel is defined for Spring, as it is the case here.

Comment: MapStruct requires you to define an annotation processor (see [installation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/installation/)). Did you configure it correctly?

Comment: @slauth it is not mandatory

Comment: @Tobb I know, but I was surprised that a non-spring mapper was found using ComponentScan annotation.

Comment: @Tobb you are not wrong, I have used ComponentScan to scan AccountMapper with Component annotation which I removed as other packages were not,  but I forgot to mentioned that. My mistake.

Comment: @slauth I have added that plugin per instruction but still the same

Comment: Instead of autowiring you can inject accountMapper without Autowired annotation. Put RequiredArgsConstructor annotation above AccountService class, delete Autowired annotation and make accountMapper variable as: private final AccountMapper accountMapper;

Comment: You can do this:



`@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AccountService {

    private final AccountRepository accountRepository;
    private final AccountMapper accountMapper;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<AccountDTO> loadAll() {
        List<Account> res = accountRepository.findAll();
        List<AccountDTO> resF = accountMapper.entitiesToDto(res);
        return resF;
    }`

Comment: Constructor injection is just another form of dependency injection… it's unlikely that this was the actual reason your problem was solved. But nevertheless, good that it's solved ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you have properly configured mapstruct.
2. Run a `mvn clean install` before starting the application, mapstruct will generate the mapper class that will be annotated with `@Component`.